# Measure on non-measurable subset

Tags: measure-theory

If $(Y, \Sigma_Y)$ is a measurable space and $X \subseteq Y$, then we can turn $X$ into a measurable space by setting 
$$ 
\Sigma_X = \{ E \cap X \mid E \in \Sigma_Y \}.
$$

When $X \in \Sigma_Y$, we have $\Sigma_X \subseteq \Sigma_Y$ and therefore any measure on $(Y, \Sigma_Y)$ restricts to one on $(X, \Sigma_X)$.

When $X \notin \Sigma_Y$, is there a sensible way to do this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in pretty much the same way. Given a measure $\mu_Y$ on $\Sigma_Y$, you can define $\mu_X$ by declaring that for any $A\in \Sigma_X$, you have $\mu_X(A)=\inf\{\mu(A')\mid A\subseteq A'\in \Sigma_Y \}$.

$\Sigma_X$ will not be contained in $\Sigma_Y$, but you can simply check directly that all the measure axioms hold.

This construction allows you to construct quite irregular measures. For example, you can find a subset $B$ of the reals which has full outer measure (with respect to any reasonable continuous measure) and such that every compact subset of $B$ is finite. Then $B$ is a metric space with lots of Borel measures, and such that no continuous measure is inner regular with respect to compact sets.

Comment: Will $\Sigma_{X}=$the set of $\mu_{X}$-measurable sets (in the sense of Carathodory extension theorem construction) ?

Comment: No. For example, if $\Sigma_Y$ is the Borel sigma-algebra on $Y$, then $\Sigma_X$ will be the Borel sigma-algebra on $X$, which is typically a proper subalgebra of the algebra of all measurable sets.